# How to set default values?

Tags: perl, hash

Let's say I have a hash like this

```
my %profile = (
    building            => $p->{account}->{building},
    email               => $p->{account}->{email},
    phone               => $p->{account}->{phone},
    );
```

The variables in `$p` can have all sorts of values when they have not been defined. I have atleast seen `undef` `~` `''`.

How do I assign a value of `-1` to e.g. `$profile{building}` if `$p->{account}->{building}` have one of these strange default values?

Are there any clever Perl way to do that?

**Update**: Any of the values can take on any of the strange default values `undef` `~` `''`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would add a function:

```
my %profile = (
    building            => scrub($p->{account}->{building}),
    email               => scrub($p->{account}->{email}),
    phone               => scrub($p->{account}->{phone}),
    );
```

and implement the default-filtering logic in the function.

Or, better yet, pre-apply the logic to $p so that you know that $p has reasonable values.

Comment: $p is read-only. How would you write the scrub function? Good idea.

Comment: Yes, +1 for being the sensible answer. @Sandra: It checks if the argument is undefined or "undefined" and returns either the argument or -1.

Comment: It'd be better and more scalable and maintanable to apply scrub to assigned default values via a loop: `my %profile = (building => $p->{account}->{building},...); $profile{$_} = scrub($profile{$_}) foreach keys %profile;

Answer (score 4):

So, if I understand you correctly, you have a bunch of bogus things being used as flags for "use the default".  I am not sure if you want to translate all of these to -1 or to field specific values.  I'll assume multiple values, just to make things trickier.

```
# Make a hash of the wanted values
my %default_values = (
    building => -1,
    email    => 'N/A',
    phone    => 'unlisted',
);

# Make a hash of the values to replace.
# Skip undef, we have to check that separately
my %bogus_values = map {$_ => undef} ('', '~', 0);

# Copy the goodies into your final structure
my  %profile = map { 
    my $val = $p->{account}{$_};
    $val = $default_values{$_}
        if( not defined $val 
            or exists $bogus_values{$_}
        );
    $_ => $val;
} keys %default_values;


# Or copy them another way
my %profile = %default_values;
$profile{$_} = $p->{account}{$_}
    for grep {
        defined $p->{account}{$_}
        and not exists $bogus_values{$_}
    } keys %default_values;
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Perl 5.10, you can use [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail):

```
my @vals = (undef, '~', "");
$profile{building} = $p->{account}{building} ~~ @vals ? -1 : $p->{account}{building};
```

Answer (score 1):

If using 5.10 or higher I would go with @eugene's solution. Otherwise ...

For untrue values (undef, '', 0) you can do

```
building => $p->{account}->{building} || -1
```

For true values you will have to check explicitly, perhaps with a regex:

```
building => !($p->{account}->{building} =~ m/~|char2|char3/)
            ? $p->{account}->{building}
            : -1
```

Combining these

```
building => $p->{account}->{building} || !($p->{account}->{building} =~ 
                                                             m/~|char2|char3/)
            ? $p->{account}->{building}
            : -1
```

Alternatively, to make this simpler and to facilitate testing and reusability you can extract this logic to a sub:

```
sub scrub {
    my $value = shift;

    if (!$value or $value =~ m/~|char2|char3/) {
        return -1;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

And then

```
my %profile = (
    building            => scrub( $p->{account}->{building} ),
    email               => scrub( $p->{account}->{email} ),
    phone               => scrub( $p->{account}->{phone} ),
    );
```

Comment: Changed sub name to 'scrub' as per @Arkadiy's answer

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing will take care of FALSE values (like `undef` or `''` or `0` or `'0'` or anything else I missed):

```
my %profile = (
    building            => $p->{account}->{building} || -1,
    email               => $p->{account}->{email} || 'N/A',
    phone               => $p->{account}->{phone} || -1,
    );
```

You can also use the *defined-or operator* `//`, which will only use the default value if `undef` is on the left side.

---

Or to take care of other values:

```
my %bad_values_hash = map { $_ => 1 } ('~', ''); # Put your bad values in here

my %profile = (
    building            => ($bad_values_hash{$p->{account}->{building}} ? -1 : $p->{account}->{building}) // -1,
    email               => ($bad_values_hash{$p->{account}->{email}} ? 'N/A' : $p->{account}->{email}) // 'N/A',
    phone               => ($bad_values_hash{$p->{account}->{phone}} ? -1 : $p->{account}->{phone}) // -1,
    );
```

(May I suggest refining the design so that it uses more consistent default values?)

Comment: Of course, I don't know your actual requirements for the defaults, but I'm sure you can figure out how to switch them to whatever suits your use case... :-)

Comment: Note that this does not take care of `"~"` but does take care of `0`.

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur: Yes, yes, I said "false-y" earlier. No need to repeat what I already said.

Comment: @Platinum, I have never seen the word 'false-y' before, and I also did not understand what you meant.

Comment: @Mauritz Hansen: Try crawling out from under your rock then, it's not that bloody uncommon. I clarified it, are you happy now?

Comment: OK @Platinum, I will take the bait. I have read MANY programming books in my life and have been a programmer for quite a while. I cannot recall seeing this anywhere. I would be much obliged if you could clarify for me the difference between 'false' and 'false-y'.

Comment: No real difference except that sometimes people limit their understanding of "false" to an actual `false` keyword. (Think Java, C#, or maybe Ruby) I realize there isn't a `false` keyword in Perl, but Perl isn't my only language.